# python get() function gives different values for class str and type str/class int and type int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a python 2 code to python 3, and just came to know the difference the type() function on both versions. I am basically pulling data from a json file using pandas. I have a variable `word = 0x00000010.` I wanted to get the value of word from the json file.

so my code goes below

`json_data = [Basically this variable have the pulled data from json file]`

`json_data.get(int(str(word),16), 'none')` gives the value that is present in python 2, but in python 3 it is returning `nan`. I am assuming it has something to do with the type(str(word)) which gives class for python 3

I have seen many questions related to this difference, but nothing actually solved my question.

Json file format :

```
{
  "color" : "red",
  "sets" :
      {
        "0x00000010":"yellow",
        "0x00000020":"red
      }
}
```

and the json_data contains the dict in "sets"

Comment: Unless you post an example `.json`, this question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @Felipe added the json format

Comment: I'm not sure why Python 2 would give you what you're looking for.  `0x00000010` is an integer equal to 16.  Therefore, `str(word)` should be `'16'`.

Comment: Ok I was keeping it simple, but the in actual I am using .get(int(str(word),16), 'none')

Comment: @DanielWalker updated

Comment: `str(word)` is still going to be `'16'`.  Try printing it out.

Comment: no, it gives me "0x00000010"

Comment: instead print(int(str(word),16)) gives 1024

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to simply access `red` via the key `0x00000010`?